# Full server-side operability of Google Optimize? Workaround?

Tags: google-optimize

With Google and other services transitioning to [offer full server-side operability](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/intro) of their marketing & analytics products, I wonder when this functionality will arrive for Optimize?
Does anyone have any insights on that or can offer a possible workaround until it's officially supported?

The stated goal is, of course, to prevent loading third-party JS and the creation of non 1st-party cookies on a users device to enhance privacy and more easily control what data is sent where.

As I understand, [server-side logic](https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments) is currently limited to defining which experiment and version to show. The rest of the logic, like displaying the actual version or reporting back still require optimize.js to be implemented on the frontend.

Any help is dearly appreciated!